# Do PHP Includes Require HTML & Body Tags?

Tags: php, include

**Do PHP Includes Require HTML & Body Tags Around Them?**

Or is this unnecessary since the server is placing the include inside of a file that already has these tags?

**Example:**

```
<?php include("includes/menu.php"); ?>
```

**WITHOUT:**

```
<nav id="menu">...</nav>
```

**or WITH:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <nav id="menu">...</nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP has *nothing* to do with HTML and couldn't care less whether there are HTML tags or not.  The point of using PHP for webpages, is to have it *generate* the HTML document to send to the browser.  When you use `include`, all PHP does is copy and paste the included file into your script (and then execute it).  When PHP runs, anything not in `<?php ?>` tags is just echoed to the screen.  PHP doesn't know/care what that data is.  When your PHP code runs, if it's delivering an HTML page then you probably want to make sure it's valid HTML (browsers tend to like that) you're generating.

Comment: the END RESULT of your includes/requires should be a valid html document. but you can include as many html snippets as you want, as long as they don't generate an invalid document. if you put `<html><body>...</body></html>` around every snippet you `include`, then your generated html will be utterly broken/bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The included HTML should not have html and body tags unless its included as like a header or footer.  If you're including some HTML content, then just include the HTML content.  Your HTML page (view source in browser) should only have 1 html and body block, not including the `<!doctype html>` tag at the very beginning.